# What Have I Done Wrong In My Python Coupled ODE code?

Tags: python, numpy, ode

I have a question regarding the accuracy of my code. I'm really new and don't really understand the reasoning behind why my code does not work as I've followed a tutorial on how to solve coupled differentiated equations.

The code follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def odes(t,s,v):
    B = 0.07173119
    g=-9.82
    m=1
    dsdt = v
    dvdt = float(g+(B*v-abs(v))/m)
    return [dsdt, dvdt]
x=np.array(100)
s=(0,2)
v=(0, 50)
x0 = [0, 0, 0]
t = np.linspace(0, 100)
x = odeint(t, s, v)
s=x[:,0]
v=x[:,1]
plt.semilogy(t, s)
plt.semilogy(t, v)
plt.show()
```

I usually get errors which I can fix by searching them up, but I never get the answer.

It is supposed to look like:

[image: GeoGebra]

Your help would be highly appreciate!
Thank you!

Comment: Read and understand the documentation of `odeint`, also the examples. The arguments of the ODE function do not fit the specifications, and the call to `odeint` is also wrong in several counts, starting with the missing ODE function.

Answer (score 0):

```
# use the correct argument format
def odes(x,t):
    s,v = x
    B = 0.07173119
    g=-9.82
    m=1
    dsdt = v
    # use the correct formula for air resistance
    dvdt =  g+ B*v*(-abs(v))/m 
    return [dsdt, dvdt]
# initial conditions, one per component
s0=2 
v0=50
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
x = odeint(odes, [s0, v0], t)
s=x[:,0]
v=x[:,1]
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.plot(t, v)
plt.show()
```

Check the physics, direction of forces vs. direction of the vertical variable. Check also the time scales where something happens, 100 s for a free-fall simulation might be too large, the spacing of 1s not fine enough.